# Notifications when someone is on the site

Tags: login, notifications

Is there anyway to get notified when someone logs on to the site or is even just browsing the site? I would like to receive email notifications when this happens but I cannot seem to find anywhere to activate this feature.

Comment: it is possible but this is not a good idea, send email to you on each visit, use google analytics tracking or any other visitor tracking plugin like [this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/hit-sniffer-blog-stats/) or [this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wassup/) or [this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/statpress/) or [this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-slimstat/)

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger [`wp_mail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) to send you an email when you have a visitor, although you may end up getting flooded with emails since it'll email you **every time** a page is viewed.

```
/**
 * Send an email with every visit.
 */
function wpse113069_email_me_every_visit() {
    wp_mail( 'me@example.net', 'You had a visitor...', 'Yea, someone was on your site!' );
}

add_action( 'wp', 'wpse113069_email_me_every_visit' );
```

You can also use [`is_user_logged_in()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) to extend this to include the page/post, the date & time of the visit, etc., or to customize the notification based on if someone is logged in or is an anonymous visitor.

```
/**
 * Send a different email based on if a visitor is signed into the site.
 */
function wpse113069_email_me() {
    $msg = 'An anonymous visitor visited!';

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $msg = 'A member visited!';
    }

    wp_mail( 'me@example.net', 'You had a visitor...', $msg );
}

add_action( 'wp', 'wpse113069_email_me' );
```

Comment: Won't this send an email every page load? I bet there is a better hook...

Comment: Yes it does, which is why I noted that in my answer. The OP asked about signing in or "just browsing the site."

Answer (score 1):

```
function whoisWatchingMe(){
    $email = "your@email.com";
    wp_mail( $email, 'You had a visitor...', 'Woopty do!' );
}

add_action( 'wp_login', 'whoisWatchingMe' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function set_mail_here() {
return 'text/html';
}

add_action( 'wp_login', 'notice_here' );

function notice_here() {
if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
return;
}
$to = 'youremail@yoursite.com';
$subject = 'Message';
$message = '<h1>Someone logged in.</h1>';

add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_mail_here' );
wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message ); 
remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_mail_here' );
}
```

source: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/email-notifications-wordpress/